# Java - Regex error when using "\\" as a delimeter

Tags: java, regex, io, java.util.scanner

The following code is from a method in a class that I am making to modify a list of file directories in a program folder. However I am trying to use "\" as a delimiter for a scanner as I only need the start of the directory "S:\" and the last part which is just name of a sub folder. So for example it looks like this:

F:\Data\Subfolder\Another

The code complies but when I run the method i get this following run time error:

java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\

And was just wondering if anyone knows what it means and how I can stop it from happening. Is it because of using the \ for a delimeter?

Note: newFolder class is a nested class

```
public void scanFiles() throws IOException{

       try
       {
        System.out.println("Sage 2015 is Installed on this machine");
        File companyFile = new File(sageFolders[8] + "\\COMPANY");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(companyFile)));
        input.useDelimiter("\\");


        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
           if(line.contains("F"))
           {
               String drive = input.next();
               String dataFolder = input.next();
               String sageFolder = input.next();
               String clientFolder = input.next();

               newFolders.add(new newFolder(drive, clientFolder));


           }

        }
        //Close the Readers
        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();

        //fileWriter = new FileWriter(companyFile);
        //bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

           //Write back to file

        //fileWriter.flush();
        //bufferedWriter.close();

       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
          System.out.println("File not Found: Moving onto next Version"); 
       }

}

class newFolder
{
    private String driveLetter;
    private String clientFolder;

    public newFolder(String driveLetter, String clientFolder)
    {
        this.driveLetter = driveLetter;
        this.clientFolder = clientFolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `\` is regex special character and also special in Java, you have to escape your java backslash with `\\` and also your regex backslash with `\\`, hence... you have four backslashes `\\\\`

You have to use:

```
input.useDelimiter("\\\\");
```